# MediaPlayer vs SoundPool for only 1 simultaneous stream

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I'm working on a game in which one single sound is played each time the phone is shaked.
Does it make sense to use a SoundPool and load sounds in the onCreate of my activity, or is it ok to create a mediaplayer each time, as shown below:

```
private void onShake() {
    MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, whipSound[currentWhip][force]);   
    mp.start();
}
```

My guess is that SoundPool is better because the sounds are loaded only once. Am I right?

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, SoundPool is much faster...

Answer (score 1):

You can create the mediaPlayer outside the `onShake` method, and then reset and start it on every shake:

```
MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, whipSound[currentWhip][force]);
...
private void onShake() {
    mp.reset();
    mp.start();
}

//or

private void onShake() {
   try {
        mp.stop();
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) { /* Ignore */
    } catch (IOException e) {/* Ignore */ }
   try { 
        mp.start(); 
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MediaPlayer failed ", e);
   }
}
```

Comment: I must load the sound everytime, because it can be different according to the shake intensity. I've used SoundPool and it's much faster.