# Slow Button firing in Android SDK for Eclipse

Tags: android, performance, audio, button, timing

I have no problem getting some audio files in eclipse:java to play properly when buttons on the android's screen are pressed and all of the audio quality sounds great. However, the program I am trying to make is a beat maker studio and you can only press the buttons so fast.  There is a slight delay in when you can press a button to fire an audio sample after pressing that same button immediately before(about .5 seconds). Obviously this presents problems with a music app when being able to press a button at the desired time is pretty important.  Any advice on how I can get my application to allow faster button presses?

```
package studio.music;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class StudioActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

MediaPlayer mp1,mp2;
Button button_one,button_two;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //The activity is being Created   Create any threads/streams here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bassfifteen);
    mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.snarenine);
        button_one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
            button_one.setOnClickListener(this);            
        button_two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
            button_two.setOnClickListener(this);        
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){ //The activity is about to become visible
    super.onStart();    
    //TODO set state for program start
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){ //The activity has become visible(it is now "resumed")
    super.onResume();
    //TODO set state for program resume
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){ // Another activity is taking focus (this activity will be "paused")
    super.onPause();
    //TODO set state for program hang
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){ // This activity is no longer visibled (it is "stopped")
    super.onStop();
    //TODO set state for program drop back
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){ // The Activity is about too be destoryed (exiting)  Destroy all threads and streams here
    super.onDestroy();
    //TODO set state for program exit
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//Where the audio is fired  
if(v == button_one){    mp1.start();}
if(v == button_two){    mp2.start();}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) which provides a low-latency playback.

A ready to use sample is available at [Android Snippets](http://www.androidsnippets.com/playing-sound-fx-for-a-game). It would be easy for you to adapt it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go for [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). Because soundpool is considerably a light weight object when comapred to MediaPlayer. here is a comparision between the two.

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/

And as you can see SoundPool is desgined for small files. 
 Here is an other link which states SoundPool does the job simple and good..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339437/603744

Comment: Thanks guys soundpool workepd PERFECTLY. miniscule lag between presses and maintained quality. appreciate the help